# An array of classes where you pass the neighbors (Conways GoL)

Tags: c#, arrays, class, reference, conways-game-of-life

i tried to create the 'Conweys game of life'. So at first i create a empty (null) arrays of tile's. Then i set a list for each neightbour tile to commit it on the creating tile on this place of the array.

```
        private static Tile[,] GenerateGeneration(int rowlenght, int colLenght)
        {

            Tile[,] newGeneration = new Tile[rowlenght, colLenght]; //Emty array 

            for (int row = 0; row < rowlenght; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < colLenght; column++)
                {
                    List<Tile> tiles = new() //Set neighbourtiles in a list
                    {
                        newGeneration[row,CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(column - 1,colLenght)], //Left
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(row - 1, rowlenght), CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(column - 1, colLenght)], //LeftAbove
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(row - 1, rowlenght), column], //Above
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((row - 1), rowlenght), CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((column + 1), colLenght)], //AboveRight
                        newGeneration[row, CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((column + 1), colLenght)], //Right
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((row + 1), rowlenght), CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(column + 1, colLenght)], //BelowRight
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((row + 1), rowlenght), column], //Below
                        newGeneration[CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow((row + 1), rowlenght), CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(column - 1, colLenght)], //BelowLeft
                    };
                    

                    newGeneration[row, column] = new Tile(tiles, row, column); //commit the neighbours
                }
            }

            return newGeneration;
        }
```

The 'CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow' methode sets the index to the upperbound of the array if it's < 0 and vice versa.

So my question is. On running this programm the most of the neighbours ar null. In my opinion all tiles should not be null, because a class is a reference type and I always pass the reference.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you wonder why so many of your tiles added to the List are null? Do you expect some of them to be null or none? The question is not about the game of life but the behaviour of arrays, right?

Comment: Please provide the code for the constructor(s) of `Tile`.

Comment: All your border tiles have at least 3 neighbours that are "not there". If you represent that by `null`, then you should expect those in your border-tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always pass the reference

This's right, but `null` is also a reference in a sense, and all your tiles are null on initial. When you do this:

```
 List<Tile> tiles = new() //Set neighbourtiles in a list
 {
     newGeneration[row, column],
     ...
 }
```

If `newGeneration[row, column]` isn't set at that moment, the tile list will contain a `null` value.

The easiest solution is full fill the array with empty tiles first:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowlenght; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < colLenght; column++)
    {
        newGeneration[row, column] = new Tile(new Tiles(), row, column);
    }
}
```

Fill the tile list in each tile next:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowlenght; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < colLenght; column++)
    {
        var tiles = newGeneration[row, column].Tiles; // Assume the tile list is public
        tiles.Add(newGeneration[row,CalculateIndexOverOrUnderflow(column - 1,colLenght)]);
        tiles.Add(...);
    }
}
```